# How do I get the type from this generic situation?

Tags: c#, generics

Im trying to write a generic base class that will allow sub classes to pass up an interface as the type and then have the baseclass call methods on the generic but I cant't work out how to do it...

```
public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : IPageModel
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        IPageModel model = new T.GetType();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

That doesn't compile, have I got the wrong end of the stick when it comes to generics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : IPageModel, new()
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        IPageModel model = new T();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Note the `new()` constraint on `T`. (See [MSDN on generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more information.)

If you *did* need the `Type` reference corresponding to `T`, you'd use `typeof(T)` - but I don't think you need it in this case.

Comment: Thanks Jon, what does that new bit at the end do? Ensure that the type is 'Newed Up' when the base class is instantiated?

Comment: @Pete2k: No - there's no inheritance going on here. It just requires that `T` has a parameterless constructor. I'll edit a link into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should do as bellow to enable creating instance:

```
public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T :IPageModel,new()
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        IPageModel model = new T();

        return View(model);
    }

}
```